# Switching Workspace with 3 finger gesture on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, workspaces, multi-touch, synaptics

hey guys i am having trouble to setup the 3 finger gesture on my Ubuntu 16.04
I download touchegg and change the action type etc..:

> ```
> <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
>     <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Left</action>
> </gesture>
>
> <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
>     <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Right</action>
> </gesture>
> ```

then on synclient TapButton3 = 1 and Clickbutton3 = 1 and put the same properties for 2 = 0.

3 finger gesture doesnt work at all. I dont want to use eastroke since then I would need to use a usb mouse.

I also checked if my touchpad on my laptop recognizes 3 fingers -> indeed it does.

What can I do guys, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I have found a way to enable the 3 finger gesture. Follow the following link: https://wdullaer.com/blog/2015/10/08/multitouch-trackpad-gestures-with-touchegg/

### When you reach Configuring Touchegg do the following:

1. Go to Keyboard setting and select shortcuts
2. on the left side choose Navigation
3. scroll all the way down and assign the following keyboard combination for "Switch to workspace left" and same for right:

- .... left = Super+Left
- .... right = Super+Right

The Super key = Windows key on the keyboard (for Windows & for Mac it is the *Command* key)

Next step is to follow the Configuring Touchegg and change the config file. The config file should look like this:

```
<application name="All">
    <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
            <action type="SEND_KEYS">Super+Left</action>
    </gesture>
    <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
            <action type="SEND_KEYS">Super+Right</action>
    </gesture>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

synclient TapButton3=0 [instead of 1]

synclient ClickButton3=0 [instead of 1]

touchegg